# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'produto' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['produto/<int:pk\\Z']

Tags: python, django, frameworks

I'm taking a beginner `Django` course, but I'm having trouble fixing the view and products link

```
NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'produto' with arguments '(1,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['produto/<int:pk\\Z']
```

I don't really know what to do to resolve this.

Index file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Django 1 - Index</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>{{curso}}</h2>
<h1>index</h1>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for produto in produtos %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'produto' produto.id %}">{{produto.nome}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{produto.preco}}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Produto
def index(request):
    produtos = Produto.objects.all()
    context = {
        'curso': 'Programação web com django',
        'produtos': produtos
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
 
def contato(request):
    return render(request, 'contato.html')
 
def produto(request, pk):
    prod = Produto.objects.get(id=pk)
 
    context = {
        'produto': prod
    }
    return render(request, 'produto.html')
```

produto.html file:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Produto</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Produto</h1>
     <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Produto</th>
                <th>Preço</th>
                <th>Estoque</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'index' %}">{{produto.nome}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{produto.preco}}</td>
                    <td>{{produto.estoque}}</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Error message:

[image]

I already tried to change the `pk` for `id` but it didn't solve.

Comment: You likely forgot to close an angle bracket, so it should be `<int:pk>` iso `<int:pk`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, contato, produto

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('contato/', contato, name='contato'),
    path('produto/<int:pk>/', produto, name='produto'),
]
```

This can help you. Just need to close your angle bracket in urls.py.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the tag in index, it should be:

```
<a href="{% url 'produto' produto.pk %}">
```

Also in make sure your URLs, are correct, like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import index, contato, produto

app_name = 'djangoappname'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', index, name='index'),
    path('contato/', contato, name='contato'),
    path('produto/<int:pk>/', produto, name='produto'),
]
```